# jquery gantt, change display so it breaks to new line if there is an overlap on dates

Tags: jquery, css, gantt-chart

I'm struggling to find any real documentation on how to do this,
basically I'm using jquery.gantt (http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/) that displays data from a database and there is a need to have multiple entries on the same line (I can do this just fine with the below code) but if the dates overlap or are the same then the chart simply overlaps itself and displays the last entry on top.
Here is my code:

```
                    values: [{
                    from: "/Date(1473802400000)/",
                    to: "/Date(1475685200000)/",
                    label: "Development",
                    customClass: "Blue"
                },{
                    from: "/Date(1473802400000)/",
                    to: "/Date(1475685200000)/",
                    label: "Development1",
                    customClass: "Blue"
                }]
```

Is there a method (most likely in the css) that will force it to render all overlapping dates on a line below?

Thanks all, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

From what we understand there is no built in support for this. However, RadiantQ's jQuery Gantt ([www.radiantq.com](http://www.radiantq.com)) has built-in support for moving overlapped tasks to newlines either by shrinking the height or by increasing the row height.

Check out these samples:

http://demos.radiantq.com/jQueryGanttDemo/Samples/OverlappedTasksRendering.htm
http://demos.radiantq.com/jQueryGanttDemo/Samples/OverlappedTasksChangingRowHeight.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rajagopal. I did look at Radiantq previously but the price is ridiculous for what it is.

Comment: Elboffor, our RadiantQ Gantt package is packed with features, I encourage you to take a closer look and contact our sales, you wouldn't be disappointed.